# Javascript function that overrides html line

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a website that references to a .js file and a .css file to format and add dynamic elements to its pages. The website gives the option to reference my own versions of those .js and .css files that I have hosted in a google code repository, and then will use those instead.

I'm trying to add another css file for mobile browsing. Currently I'm using @media arguments within the current css, but I'd like to have two separate css files.

Is there some code I could add to my .js file that would override the html, such that:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="desktop.css" ...
```

Turns into:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="mobile.css" ...
```

When the JS detects a mobile browswer. Keep in mind the js file is referenced further on in the HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: Use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) within your `link` tags.

Comment: It seems like the OP does not have the ability to change the HTML source... At least that's how I interpret the question.  Also, the OP mentions that he's using media arguments.  Is that the same thing as media queries?

Comment: Your code might be able to change the html, but it won't change the fact that desktop.css has already been loaded and applied to the page.

Comment: I understand now, yes the CSS is loaded before the js, so I'm trying out the @import now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries on `@import` rules:

```html
<link href="master.css" …
```

```css
@import url(desktop.css) (min-width:800px);
@import url(mobile.css) (max-width:700px);
```

Comment: Just '@import url(desktop.css)' works, but adding on any conditions afterwards causes no css to be loaded. I'm moving around the screen width using the google console without success so a possible syntax error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pls try this

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">');
    }
    else {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css">');
    }
```

And yes, it's a [good practice](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to use CSS `@media` queries

Comment: If the OP's JavaScript gets included _AFTER_ the css file is included, he'll probably have to manipulate existing elements in the DOM rather than simply appending to the document...

Comment: Unfortunately the js is loaded after, but thank you! Sorry I wasn't more clear in my post.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some code I could add to my .js file that would override the html?

Sure, you could override the html, but what's the point? It'll be too late, the browser will already have loaded and applied desktop.css.

If you want to maintain two separate css files, what you need to do is remove your static link tag, and apply the correct stylesheet dynamically based on browser detection:

```
var stylesheet=document.createElement("link");
stylesheet.type="text/css";
stylesheet.rel="stylesheet";
if (// detect mobile browser) {
    stylesheet.href=mobile.css;
}
else {
    stylesheet.href=desktop.css;
}
document.head.appendChild(stylesheet);
```

Comment: It would go in your .js file.